# Interpretation of Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I'm currently taking the second part of a two semester course in quantum mechanics and while discussing the interaction of matter and radiation some Feynman diagrams came up.
[image]
The context is "lightscattering", meaning that we look at processes where a photon described by $\vec k, \lambda$ gets scattered into a photon $\vec k', \lambda'$, where $\vec k$ is the wave vector and $\lambda$ the polarization. The states $a$
and $b$ are one-particle states.

In the end we are interested in figuring out transition-amplitudes of the form
$$\langle b; \vec k',\lambda'\vert e^{-iH(t-t_0)/\hbar}\vert a;\vec k,\lambda\rangle,$$
where the Hamiltonian is given by
$$H=\frac{1}{2 m} \sum_{i}\left[\vec{p}_{i}-\frac{q_{i}}{c} \vec{A}\left(\vec{r}_{i}, t\right)\right]^{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{q_{i} q_{j}}{\left|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_{j}\right|}+\int d^{3} r \frac{E_{\perp}^{2}+B^{2}}{8 \pi}$$

---

Now to the actual question: Can someone explain to me what is going on in (C)? I think I have an idea what is happening in (A) and (B), but when it comes to (C) I'm completely lost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B and C simply differ in whether the charged particle absorbs the photon with momentum $k$ *before* or *after* it emits the photon with momentum $k’$.

Comment: It's been a while. Pretty hazy.. But I seem to recall there's some difference in polarization, directions of spins, or something like that. Anybody? I could be totally out of it here, but I seem to recall this is relevant to one of the "big name" tests of Bell's theorem.

Comment: In both B and C you have to deal with the polarizations of the charged particle (unless it has spin $0$) and the polarizations of the photons.

Comment: Just to be sure, there is a point where the two photon-lines „intersect“... What is this supposed to be? As far as I understand photons can‘t interact with each other (since they have no charge..), so how am I supposed to read that vertex..

Comment: That isn’t a vertex. There is nothing happening there. Imagine the two photons as not being in the same plane. It’s like in circuit diagrams where sometimes wires “cross” each other without being connected.

Comment: What I am confused about is diagram A. If the charged particle is an electron, there is no such allowed vertex where four lines would meet.

Comment: It’s best to draw Feynman diagrams with a dot at the actual vertices.

Comment: Could you explain why this would not be possible if the involved particle was an electron? The notes say that we are dealing with „hydrogen-like“ particles (not sure what exactly this is supposed to mean...)

Comment: When you work out the Feynman rules for the QED action, there is only one kind of vertex, with two charged fermion lines and one photon line, like you see in B and C. But it sounds like you are dealing with the $a$ and $b$ lines being an atom, not an elementary particle. I’ve forgotten how that case works. I guess a four-vertex is allowed, but I don’t remember why. Maybe someone else can explain this.

Comment: The vertex with 2 photons is from the nonrelativistic approximation where you get the vector potential squared. If you look back to the relativistic case, this corresponds to terms where 1 photon creates a virtual electron positron pair where the electron is the outgoing particle, the incoming electron interacts with the positron and photon. Nonrelativistically, the positron terms are replaced with these 2 photon vertices. That is, the 4-vertex is the approximate contribution of the other 2 diagrams in the relativistic theory when the intermediate particle is a positron.

Comment: @user200143 Thanks for explaining this!